# Resposta de cadastro feito com sucesso em php

Tags: php, javascript, mysqli

Estou tentando fazer um retorno de "Cadastro feito com sucesso ", mas sempre cai no else, ele não está contando o numero de linhas.

```
public function adicionarAluno(string $nome, string $matricula, string $endereco, string $tel): void{

        $adicionar=$this->mysql->prepare("INSERT INTO aluno (nome,matricula,endereco,tel) VALUES (?,?,?,?);");
        $adicionar->bind_param('ssss',$nome,$matricula,$endereco,$tel);
        $adicionar->execute();
        $teste=$adicionar->num_rows;
        if($teste > 0){
            echo "<script>alert('Cadastro realizado com sucesso!');</script>";
        }else{
            echo "<script>alert('Falha!');</script>";
        }


    }
```

Comment: substitui $adicionar->num_rows por $adicionar->affected_rows

Comment: Muito obrigado, agora deu certo!!

Answer (score 0):

O cadastro tá sendo realizado? Ou ele vai direto pro else sem cadastrar?

Você adaptou essa função de alguma outra linguagem? É que não me recordo de precisar usar declaração de tipo de variável (string) em php, e nunca fiz nenhuma função que usasse o "void".

Tenta deixar assim e vê se funciona, caso não dê certo retorna aqui e deixar o código do seu arquivo de conexão:

```
public function adicionarAluno($nome, $matricula, $endereco, $tel){

    $adicionar=$this->mysql->prepare("INSERT INTO aluno (nome,matricula,endereco,tel) VALUES (?,?,?,?);");
    $adicionar->bind_param('ssss',$nome,$matricula,$endereco,$tel);
    $adicionar->execute();
    $teste=$adicionar->num_rows;
    if($teste > 0){
        echo "<script>alert('Cadastro realizado com sucesso!');</script>";
    }else{
        echo "<script>alert('Falha!');</script>";
    }


}
```

Comment: Declarações de tipo dentro das funções são relativamente antigas PHP 5. alguma coisa. Agora declarações do tipo do valor de retorno é do PHP 7. Dá uma olhada: https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/functions.arguments.php#functions.arguments.type-declaration

Comment: Ops.. esquecei de colocar o link para declarações do tipo do retorno https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/functions.returning-values.php

Comment: Opa, obrigado pelos links, vão ser de grande ajuda. Faz tempo que não mexo com PHP, e não sei quase nada sobre o 7, vai me ajudar  bastante =)